# Can getters be marked `noexcept`?

Tags: c++, getter, noexcept

For a class such as this:

```
class CharMatrix
{
public:
.
.
.

private:
    int m_Y_AxisLen;
    int m_X_AxisLen;
    char m_fillCharacter;
    mutable std::vector< std::vector<char> > m_characterMatrix;
}


inline const int& CharMatrix::getY_AxisLen( ) const
{
    return m_Y_AxisLen;
}

inline const int& CharMatrix::getX_AxisLen( ) const
{
    return m_X_AxisLen;
}

inline const char& CharMatrix::getFillCharacter( ) const
{
    return m_fillCharacter;
}

inline std::vector< std::vector<char> >& CharMatrix::getCharacterMatrix( ) const
{
    return m_characterMatrix;
}
```

Can one mark all of these getter member functions as `noexcept`? Is there any chance that any of these getters might throw?

Another question is that can `operator[]` of `std::vector` throw? I checked [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) but there was no mention of exceptions.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241550/discussion-on-question-by-digito-evo-can-getters-be-marked-noexcept).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can one mark all of these getter member functions as noexcept?
> Is there any chance that any of these getters might throw?

You can mark them as `noexcept`.

A simple return (by reference) cannot throw.
A return by copy might throw depending of the copied type.

> can operator[] of std::vector throw?

- For valid index, no.
- For invalid index, your are in UB. It is not marked as `noexcept` to let the opportunity to "compiler" to add extra checks and possibly handle failure with exception.